# Unexpected behaviour on currency formatting when using English in Germany

Tags: java, kotlin, formatting, internationalization, currency

I'm using NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale locale) to render price values. for my understanding, the locale's country defines the currency, and the locale's language defines the style to render. But when using Locale("en", "DE") it works different, as seen in the test below:

```kotlin
    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvSource(
        value = [
            "de; DE; 1,23 €",
            "de; GB; 1,23 £",
            "en; GB; £1.23",
            "en; DE; €1.23", // <- fails because result is "1,23 €"
        ],
        delimiter = ';',
    )
    fun `formatting`(givenLanguage: String, givenCountry: String, expectedResult: String) {
        assertEquals(
            expectedResult,
            NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale(givenLanguage, givenCountry)).format(1.23)
        )
    }
```

Formatting everything based on currencyCode works as expected

```kotlin
val nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale("en")) // no country "DE"
nf.currency = Currency.getInstance("EUR")
println(nf.format(1.23))
// => €1.23
```

But adding country "de" here results in the same issue

```kotlin
val nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale("en", "DE"))
nf.currency = Currency.getInstance("EUR")
println(nf.format(1.23))
// => 1,23 €
```

Does someone has an explanation for that?

Comment: "for my understanding, the locale's country defines the currency" <- What makes you think that? In your code examples you clearly define the currency yourself with `Currency.getInstance("EUR")`, which is why it is using Euro in both examples.

Comment: The test case `"de; GB; 1,23 £",` shows that the german formatting is applied to british pound. Thats why.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with is to never pass the country to the Locale-argument of `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale locale)`. Instead, I extract the currency from the country and define it directly into the `NumberFormat` instance. Pretty hacky.

In fact I do the following:

```kotlin
val nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale("en"))
nf.currency = Currency.getInstance(Currency.getInstance(Locale("", "DE")).currencyCode)
println(nf.format(1.23))
// €1.23
```

Side note:

In some cases, the formatting uses the currency code, instead of the symbol. For example British Pound in Spanish (`language="es"`, `country="GB"`) gets formatted to `1,23 GBP` instead of `1,23 £`. So if one wants to always use currency symbols I would suggest to always substitute `currencyCode` by the `currencySymbol`:

```kotlin
println(nf.format(1.23).replace(nf.currency.currencyCode, nf.currency.symbol))
// 1,23 £
```